# How to make a only Title page without the main text

Tags: formatting

I have the following source file:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,man,natbib]{apa6}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}


\title{A New Probability Distribution for Response Times\\
and\\
a New Way to Test its Validity}
\shorttitle{A New Probability Distribution}
\author{Ad H. G. S. van der Ven}
\affiliation{Institute for Learning and Development, Department of Pedagogy, Radboud University Nijmegen, Montessorilaan 3, 6500 HE Nijmegen, the Netherlands}

\abstract{Text}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
Text
\section{Tasks}
Text
\section{Statistical Analysis}
Text
\section{Discussion}
Text
\section*{References}

\end{document}
```

If I run the source text in Latex then I get only the chapters with the  texts. However I want to have the opposite. I only want the title, the short title, the author, the affiliation and the abstract without the main text.

How should I do it?

Comment: You mean Table of Contents?

Comment: It's not quite clear what you want.  But you're missing `\maketitle` in order to make the title information, and you're missing `\tableofcontents` in order to have the table of contents.  My main point of confusion is why you don't want the main text to appear, and what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I want to submit a paper to a Journal. This Journal requires:the following: Author/Title Page - A page containing the manuscript title, list of authors, abstract and acknowledgements. If I include \maketitle then Latex produces an error.

Comment: It is as if \documentclass[a4paper,man,natbib]{apa6}
automatically omits the manuscript title, list of authors, abstract and acknowledgements in the output file.